# Get index of array from name

Tags: arrays, bash

Fooling around in Bash (just for fun) and discovered that you can reference an array and gets its value from the variable's name:

```
nick@nick-lt:~$ ARR=(one two);
nick@nick-lt:~$ ARRAYINDIRECT="ARR[@]"
nick@nick-lt:~$ echo "${!ARRAYINDIRECT}"
one two
```

I was interested if using the same approach we could also get the indexes of the array. Usually, I'd do that by doing:

```
nick@nick-lt:~$ ARR=(one two); echo "${!ARR[@]}"
0 1
```

but I can't find a correct syntax to do so. Here's a few ways I tried:

```
nick@nick-lt:~$ ARR=(one two); ARRAYINDIRECT="ARR[@]"; echo "${!!ARRAYINDIRECT}"
bash: !ARRAYINDIRECT}: event not found

ARR=(one two); ARRAYINDIRECT="!ARR[@]"; echo "${!ARRAYINDIRECT}"
bash: !ARR[@]: event not found

# Increasingly desperate attempts...
nick@nick-lt:~$ ARR=(one two); ARRAYINDIRECT="\!ARR[@]"; echo "${!ARRAYINDIRECT}"

nick@nick-lt:~$ ARR=(one two); ARRAYINDIRECT="ARR[@]"; echo "${!${!ARRAYINDIRECT}}"
bash: ${!${!ARRAYINDIRECT}}: bad substitution
nick@nick-lt:~$ ARR=(one two); ARRAYINDIRECT="ARR[@]"; echo "${\!!ARRAYINDIRECT}"
bash: !ARRAYINDIRECT}: event not found
nick@nick-lt:~$ ARR=(one two); ARRAYINDIRECT="ARR[@]"; echo "${!\!ARRAYINDIRECT}"
bash: ${!\!ARRAYINDIRECT}: bad substitution
```

**Question:** is it possible to get the array of indexes of an array after reference by name?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes you can, with anubhava's answer! As stated from the first word in the first line in the first sentence, *Fooling around in Bash (just for fun)*, so doing that wouldn't teach me anything. If you want a valid use case, passing an array to a function by name is something I do to manipulate them (even works on `local` vars!), so this would be great if I was iterating and mapping the elements of an array to another and I wanted to retain the index structure in the new array. In fact, it'd be great for any index-based manipulation when passed by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using BASH 4.2+ then you can use `declare -n`:

```
arr=(one two)

declare -n arrayindirect=arr

echo "${arrayindirect[@]}"
one two

echo "${!arrayindirect[@]}"
0 1

declare -p arrayindirect
declare -n arrayindirect="arr"
```

Comment: Awesome - much easier to implement than expected too!